# jQuery ajax php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have never been in contact with ajax. Can I get some help?

I know how to call a php script.

Example:

```
<script>
        function myCall() {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(msg) {
                $("#mybox").html(msg);
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        }
    </script>
```

How can I get a response from function? If my ajax.php has function

```
<?php 

function example(){
  return "blablalba.....";
}
?>
```

How should my script looks like?

Answer (score 3):

> How can i get a response from function?

The same way you get a response from any other PHP script. The Ajax is irrelevant.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // or whatever
print example();
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script just needs to display content as it would if you loaded it directly in the browser, using `echo` or simply closing your PHP tag `?>` and outputting HTML or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return, you should send actual output. For example: a JSON encoded string or array, with the correct content type. The result will populate to the variable mentioned in `request.done`, i.e. `msg`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use echo rather than return.

ajax.php

```
<?php 
    function example(){
        echo "blablalba.....";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of which you are using. 
Since you specified content is HTML, your response will be a string with HTML code (as if you wrote it in notepad).
But AJAX as far as I know wont get response unless "echo 'html code'" is used in php.

```
<?php  
echo '<body><div>Response from php script</div></body>';
?>
```

So fix your php code first. Then in AJAX set "data" as function argument and use it inside function. Data will be your response from php.

```
.done(function(data){
var smth = data;
});
```